# MVC Entity Framework get one column as an array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

my application is asp.net MVC3 using Entity Framework.  I am trying to get a list of one column from a table as an array using the following:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //var list = db.CasesProgresses.ToList();
            var SeriesList = GetSeriesList(Learner_ID);
            return View();
        }



        public List<string> GetSeriesList(string item)
        {
            // get DataTable dt from somewhere.
            List<string> sList = new List<string>();
            foreach (CasesProgress row in db.CasesProgresses)
            {
                sList.Add(row[0].ToString());
            }
            return sList;  
        }
```

I get two errors:

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'caseprog.Models.CasesProgress' and
The name 'Learner_ID' does not exist in the current context
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: What do you expect `row[0]` to contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 foreach (CasesProgress row in db.CasesProgresses)
 {
   sList.Add(row.SomePropertyYouNeed.ToString());
 }
```

if you are using a foreach, there is no `[0]`. If you were using a normal `for (int i =0; i < list.Count; i ++;)` then you would be able to do that. But then ofcourse you would have to change the `0` to `i`, and you would still need to access a property. Well you wouldn't *have* to do that if your List had a different type, but in your current example you will need to add a String.

Comment: Thank you so much I changed SomePropertyYouNeed to Learner_ID; worked great.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to read the Property name of your `CasesProgress` object

Change this

```
sList.Add(row[0].ToString());
```

to

```
sList.Add(row.YourPropertyNameHereWhichIsOfStringType);
```

If the Property is not of string type, (*ex : Integer / decimal* ) you may apply `ToString()` method on that and then add to the string collection.

```
sList.Add(row.Learner_ID.ToString());
```

Assuming `Learner_ID` is a property of `CasesProgress` class with numeric type.

Answer (score 1):

```
The name 'Learner_ID' does not exist in the current context 
GetSeriesList(Learner_ID);
```

Learner_ID - is not defined in your action and you can remove it, because parameter in GetSeriesList(string item)  is not used (also remove parameter).

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'caseprog.Models.CasesProgress'
```

In `foreach` row is separate item from collection, that's why you shoud access it by property with dot notation `row.Property`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep it simple and use the 'usual' syntax

```
var list = db.CasesProgresses.Select(o=>o.YourPropertyName).ToList();
```

If its an int and you need it as a string list simply replace YourPropertyName with  YourPropertyName.ToString() above

Comment: Thanks Adam, I got this error:Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.  The YourPropertyName is bigint.